# How to indeed center object in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window, layout-manager

I have a class which extends a Jframe, and i have it centered using `setLocationRelativeTo(null);`. The layouManager is `null` aswell.

My JFrame:

```
mport com.sxf.protocol.chat.util.window.AbstractField;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class Field extends AbstractField {

    private Container cp;

    public Field() {
        super("Test");

        buildWindow();
    }

    private void buildWindow() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frameWidth, frameHeight));
        setResizable(false);

        cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(null);

        initComponents();

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        JLabel border = new JLabel("");
        label.setSize(200, 30);
        label.setLocation((frameWidth - label.getWidth()) / 2, (frameHeight - label.getHeight()) / 2);
        border.setBounds(frameWidth / 2, 0, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight);
        label.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        border.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(255, 0, 0)));

        cp.add(label);
        cp.add(border);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Field();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I added to border to see if its centered correctly or not.

The AbstractField (only some calculations in it):

```
public abstract class AbstractField extends JFrame {

    private final static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    private static final Dimension frameSize = new Dimension(screenSize.width / 4, screenSize.height / 4);
    protected static final int frameWidth;
    protected static final int frameHeight;
    protected static final int x;
    protected static final int y;

    static {
        frameWidth = frameSize.width;
        frameHeight = frameSize.height;
        x = (screenSize.width - frameWidth) / 2;
        y = (screenSize.height - frameHeight) / 2;
    }

    public AbstractField(String title) {
        super(title);
    }
}
```

But when i try to center my components, e.g. the JLabel, doing
`(frame.getWidth - component.getWidth) / 2`, and the same for the height, it is not actually centered but a little bit to the right.

Is that due to a native moved beginning of the jframe and can i calculate that?

Comment: 1) `AbstractField extends JFrame` Please give classes descriptive, logical and sensible names. For example, this class might be abstract, but in no sense is it a field like `JTextField`. `AbstractFrame` would make more sense. 2) `private final static..` Using the `static` modifier usually hides bigger problems, while creating problems of its own. Remove all instances of `static` and figure out how to use non-static instances of fields. 3) `..frameSize = new Dimension(screenSize.width / 4, screenSize.height / 4);` This is at best a guess as to how big to make the frame. Instead ..

Comment: .. `pack()` it to ensure it is the (smallest) size it needs to be to display the contents. 4) `x = (screenSize.width - frameWidth) / 2;` (a) Not only are `x` and `y` already defined for mot components and windows, but they are used for other things. Give your attributes different names. (b) To center a window on-screen, call `window.setLocationRelativeTo(null;)` after all components are added. 5) Don't extend frame without good reason. What is the reason here?  6) `cp.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', ..

Comment: .. screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 7) `label.setLocation((frameWidth - label.getWidth()) / 2, (frameHeight - label.getHeight()) / 2);` This does not account for the frame decorations or 'chrome'. This is why we typically do everything re positioning in a `JPanel` which is added to the frame.

Comment: 8) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 9) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It's more like ab little private project but i will try to transpose your tips.

Comment: *"It's more like ab little private project but i will try to transpose your tips."* It could be smaller if you toss that code out completely and start again, but do it the *right* way this time. What I see above is a heaping helping of voodoo code.

Answer (score 2):

> How to indeed center object in a JFrame?

Indeed add it as the only component added to a `JPanel` with a `GridBagLayout`. Use that panel as the content pane.

Example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CenteredLabel {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    CenteredLabel() {
        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        JLabel centeredLabel = new JLabel("Test");
        centeredLabel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        ui.add(centeredLabel);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            CenteredLabel o = new CenteredLabel();

            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't like using those layouts and i have a bunch of items. I found out that the native indent is 10 pixel, so after calculating the middle of the frame i have to subtract 10 :D

Comment: *"native indent is 10 pixel"* On which OS? That's the thing. Frame decorations change. So while you may get it 'right' for one machine, OS or PLAF, it will change on the next. *"I don't like using those layouts"* If you're refusing to use the correct tool for the job simply because you don't 'like' a layout, this will be much harder - and will probably fail.

Comment: @HerbertGrönemeyer "I don't like using those layouts"  unfortunately that is what you should do. Use layout managers and avoid null layout managers.